# make: Nothing to be done for first.pdf

Tags: linux, makefile

I'm a newbie to linux and make, I've written a makefile to automatically compile the .tex file to .pdf. But when i call make, it said "Nothing to be done for 'first.pdf'", here's my makefile:

```
    TEXFILE= first.tex
    PDF= $(TEXFILE:.tex=.pdf)

    .tex.pdf:
            pdflatex $<
    $(PDF):$(TEXFILE)
    view:
            evince $(PDF)
    clean:
            @rm -f \
            $(TEXFILE:.tex=.log) \
            $(TEXFILE:.tex=.aux) \
            $(TEXFILE:.tex=.toc)
```

could any one tell me what's wrong with it?

Comment: I guess, `first.pdf` is newer than `first.tex`.

Comment: And you may want to use `remake -x` to debug your `Makefile`. So install `remake`

Comment: @Matthias but there is no first.pdf there...

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch i've installed it, and i use remake -x, it just prints the same sentence...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably, one of the suffixes is not known.
You can add a `.SUFFIXES` directive:

```
TEXFILE=first.tex
PDF=$(TEXFILE:.tex=.pdf)

.SUFFIXES: .tex .pdf
# etc.
```

However, better than using outdated suffix rules, you should use pattern rules:

```
%.pdf : %.tex 
        pdflatex $<
```

Comment: and one more question, i've got the .pdf, but it is not opened, and the log,aux,toc files are not cleaned, how could it be?

Comment: @PhilipZhang: Did you call `make view`, and `make clean`, respectively?

Comment: @PhilipZhang: make will only clean files after using them in a rule if they are explicitly mentioned as dependencies of that rule, and as targets of rules that produce them. Another problem is that you typically need to run pdflatex multiple times and you may also need to run other commands in between. So a correct Makefile for building LaTeX documents can grow quite complex. I have written my own attempt, but examples can also be found online.

Answer (score 0):

This issue exists if one splits writing into multiple .tex files.
`make` can be successful, but unless you modify the `first.tex` you will be getting:

> "Nothing to be done for 'first.pdf'

## Makefile for multiple inputs changes

```
# ...

# include all text files from current directory
SOURCES := $(shell find . -name '*.tex')
# include files figs directory ...
SOURCES += $(shell find ./figs)

# ...

# add sources here will cause recompilation when something is modified
$(PDF):$(TEXFILE) $(SOURCES)

# some phony targets
.PHONY: all pdf view clean
```